# can't ssh to server after switch off/on

Tags: server, nextcloud

I was starting to feel confident with my Ubuntu server machine with a Nextcloud 12 setup but I can't ssh to it anymore since it was shut down, neither can I connect my Next cloud clients anymore.

Is there a specific task to do after the switch on to make it accessible again ?

For the record, if it helps, I installed the latest Ubuntu server distro on a MacMini and then followed this tutorial for Nextcloud 12 https://youtu.be/nXr_muYB6xI

Thanks beforehand for any advice :-)

---

**EDIT 1:**

As stated in the comment the ip address of my server appear to have change because of the switch off/on.

Don't know why but I can connect again through the new ip.

Comment: There Shouldn't be. I use Google Cloud and Switch it off all the time to save Money and I can always ssh right back in. You are ssh'ing with a key file or password? Also, is the IP set to Static?

Comment: You might want to attach a monitor and keyboard, log in , look at the ``/var/log/syslog`` or read ``journalctl -b0`` and look for ssh related issues.  Of course, you may find that the problem is something else altogether, but nothing replaces a first-hand look on console.

Comment: Oh, NextCloud 12 is some sort of Home Server? I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: WAWWW!  I checked my ip address and in the end it had changed, this is why I was unable to connect again : I was not pointing to the corect address with ssh ! ----- Id this normal for it to change ip because of a switch off/on?!